# i get error when i run sudo npm run serve

Tags: vue.js, npm

I was getting error when i was installing npm but it seemed to me that it run fine. I created default app and i tried `sudo npm run serve` but i get this error
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /home/00/00/00/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/00/00/00/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.

---

I tried:
`npm cache clear` & `sudo npm cache clear` and i get error starting with As of npm@5, the npm cache self-heals from corruption issues.
**NPM VERSION 8.18.0**

Comment: Don't run `sudo` with NPM. Mostly a bad configuration when you need to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it, i needed to add `package.json` file to my app.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/32559405)

Comment: @AlexiusDIAKOGIANNIS, this appears to be a self-answer, not a comment. Though OP could improve it with some details.